# Read lines with streams and save by blocks

Tags: java, file, stream

I have a Java process (CronJob of K8S) that read about 500K of lines of a file (in Google Cloud Storage)

I'm reading each line with Java Streams, but "sometimes" the process can be stopped (for example: by network issues) and the process restarts itself.

I'd like to continue in the same place where the process stopped. There is no database to persist anything.

I was thinking in the next steps:

- Read the file with: `Files.lines(path).forEach`
- Do the process stuff
- Store in an ArrayList the lines that have been read
- And delete those lines in the original file.
- If the process stops, the next execution, it reads the file in the same place.

But my problem is in the last point.

I've tried with:

```
Files.write(path, listTmp,  StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

But to work fine, I have to load the whole content of the file in an ArrayList, then remove the lines read, and persist the result.

**Is there any option to avoid reading the whole content of the file**? Maybe store the number of the line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why continue from the same place? Isn't reading the file once again for a full reprocess a little more resilient?

Comment: if you are reading line by line of a file, just keep track of what line number you have read, then if your connection gets interrupted you know how many lines you can jump/skip the next time you start reading from the file to line number you left off at

Comment: Hi @aksappy the process can take about 6 hours, so there is no option to restart from the beginning. Thanks for your response